# Was there a poem by Aleister Crowley that involved a mechanical girl?

Tags: identification-request, aleister-crowley

Was there a poem by [Aleister Crowley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleister_Crowley) that involved a mechanical girl?

I remember finding one with a straight-forward title, like "The Mechanical Girl" or something, when looking up early uses of pre-computer humanoid automatons in literature...

But now I can't find it, and I'm not sure if it's actually by some other author around the same time, like [Samuel Liddell MacGregor Mathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Liddell_MacGregor_Mathers).

I've gone through Wikipedia's [List of fictional robots and androids in literature before the 20th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_robots_and_androids#19th_century_and_earlier), and nothing rings a bell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was right about the author, it was just the title being one word off.

It's "The Automatic Girl" by Alesister Crowley, from PDF page 143 of the *erotic* poetry book, [*Snowdrops From A Curate's Garden*](https://www.100thmonkeypress.com/biblio/acrowley/books/snowdrops_1903/snowdrops.pdf).

The poem is mentioned in only about 261 pages on the internet, according to Google, and isn't mentioned on Wikipedia, so it's not that well known.

Answer (score 3):

The Complete Works of Aleister Crowley are [available online](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupname?key=Crowley%2C%20Aleister%2C%201875-1947), linked from the University of Pennsylvania website. I checked the contents list for each of the Volumes I, II, and III, but didn't see anything that looked like "The Mechanical Girl".

The closest possibilities I saw were the poems in Crowley's collection *Rodin in Rime*, apparently inspired by the art of the French sculptor [Auguste Rodin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auguste_Rodin). This poetry collection is [available as a *searchable* PDF](https://www.100thmonkeypress.com/biblio/acrowley/books/rodin_in_rime_1907/rodin_text.pdf), and the word "mechanical" doesn't appear anywhere, nor various synonyms and related terms which I tried in both French and English (the titles of these poems are in French, the poems themselves in English).

Comment: ... Is there a "The Automatic Girl"? Apparently in *Snowdrops From A Curate's Garden*? ... Because now after months of thought... And "Automatic Girl" coming to mind... I thought I was mistaken, but right when I was about to say I was... I go look it up...

Comment: @Malady Yes, [there is](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1512099)! Would you like to add that as a self-answer? I'd feel bad taking the credit for it in my answer since you discovered it.

Comment: Yeah, I'll make a self answer... But I wouldn't feel right about doing that without a link to the actual text... Is it not available anywhere? ... And if you find one, I'd be totally fine with you taking the credit as a better searcher!

Comment: @Malady [Here it is](https://www.100thmonkeypress.com/biblio/acrowley/books/snowdrops_1903/snowdrops.pdf), but be warned: this is a collection of *erotic* poetry, and that includes the one you're asking about.

Comment: And posted! ... Thanks for all your help! ... I'd like a link from that University of Pennsylvania site, for *Snowdrops*... For that more academic source feel... But I can't seem to find one? Huh.